# Error 13 in Visual Studio 2013 Express: output name

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, naudio

So I am trying to build a media player and I am following a tutorial on YouTube.
 
I followed the tutorial and entered the code 1 for 1 and all of the instances of the name 'output' gave an Error 13.  I have added the NAudio 1.6.3 dll as well.Maybe I got the wrong version?

Here is the link to the YouTube video... [C# Audio Tutorial 1 - Wave File with NAudio](http://youtu.be/6XvWRzWzgNI)

And here is my code...

```
    using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Naudio_Tutorial
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader wave = null;

        private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut wave = null;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
            open.Filter = "Wave File (*.wav)|*.wav;";
            if (open.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;


            DisposeWave();

            wave = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(open.FileName);
            Output = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
            Output.Init(new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(wave));
            Output.Play();

            pauseButton.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (output != null)
            {
                if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Playing) output.Pause();
                else if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Paused) output.Play();

            }
        }

        private void DisposeWave()
        {
            if (output != null)
            {
                if (output.PlaybackState == NAudio.Wave.PlaybackState.Playing) output.Stop();
                output.Dispose();
                output = null;
            }
            if (wave != null)
            {
                wave.Dispose();
                wave = null;
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            DisposeWave();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I notice is that you are declaring two different objects with the same name. 
In my experience, the application shouldn't even compile because this would be a conflict.

**This line:**

```
private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut wave = null;
```

**Should be changed to:**

```
private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut output = null;
```

The compiler will complain because you are attempting to access an object that has not been declared.
The following will cause an exception such as the one you have described:

```
Output = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
Output.Init(new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(wave));  
Output.Play();
```

Also, just a tip. Error 13 isn't descriptive enough. Including the entire error message and stacktrace will help others help you.

[Error 13 - ERROR_INVALID_DATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376931(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared `Output`. Add a `var` keyword if you intend to only use `Output` locally in this method

```
var Output = new NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut();
```

Or declare `Output` as field if you need to access it later (which seems to be your case):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut output;

    ...
}
```

Also note that C# is case sensitive. Either write `output` OR `Output` but don't mix the two variants. In C# camelCase is preferred for fields, method parameters and local variables; PascalCase is preferred for type names, properties and methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is your problem:

`private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut wave = null;`

it should be:

`private NAudio.Wave.DirectSoundOut Output = null;`